# "Error: No callback provided to pbkdf2" when using async await

Tags: node.js, async-await, pbkdf2

I want to write an async function for pbkdf2 password hash using crypto module in Nodejs. While the randomBytes function works fine, I get the following erroron running pbkdf2 with await: "Error: No callback provided to pbkdf2".

I know a workaround could be using pbkdf2Sync() but I can't understand why the async version does not work or is it correct to await on a sync function?

Node v 8.10.0

```js
async function hashPassword(password){
 let salt;
 let hash;
 let pass;
 try{
  salt = await Crypto.randomBytes(Config.SALT_BYTES);
  hash = await Crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, Config.ITERATIONS, Config.HASH_BYTES, 'sha512');
  pass = salt+hash;
  return pass;
 }
 catch(err){
  console.log('ERR: ', err);
 }
}
```

Comment: The point of PBKDF2 is to consume CPU time and a general iteration value should consume ~100ms. The security lies in the CPU time consumed.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for the comment. I understood your point but I didn't get its relation with my question. So you say pbkdf2 must be called synchronous? what about randomBytes function that called asynchronous with no problem (Still CPU intensive method)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution would be to wrap the method in a promise. Any method that requires a callback can be converted into one that supports async/await in this way.

```
function pbkdf2Async(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest) {
    return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, (err, key) => {
            err ? rej(err) : res(key);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

util.promisify was added in: v8.0.0

> Takes a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e.
> taking an (err, value) => ... callback as the last argument, and
> returns a version that returns promises.

```js
const {promisify} = require('util');
const {randomBytes, pbkdf2} = require('crypto');
const randomBytesAsync = promisify(randomBytes);
const pbkdf2Async = promisify(pbkdf2);

async function hashPassword(password, options = {}){
  let params = Object.assign({
    saltlen: 16,
    iterations: 10000,
    keylen: 64,
    digest: 'sha512'
  }, options) // merge default and provided options
  
  const {saltLen, iterations, keylen, digest} = params;
  const salt = await randomBytesAsync(saltlen);
  const hash = await pbkdf2Async(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest);  
  return salt + ':' + hash;
}
```

[Full example with generation password hash and checking password](https://replit.com/@dangelzm/HashPassword#index.js)

Answer (score 1):

The [Crypto.pbkdf2()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) function takes 6 arguments, with the 6th being the callback which is required.

If you want a synchronous call you should use [crypto.pbkdf2Sync()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want a synchronous call, I want an asynchronous call with asyc/await (No callback). randomBytes function also takes a callback as its last argument if you want to use a callback style but if you call it with await and omit the callback (as shown in my code for randomBytes and works fine) it is still asynchronous (As far as I understood async/await). How can I have an async call on pbkdf2 with async/await (No callback like randomBytes) ?

Comment: If you look at the docs for [randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) you can see that the callback function is optional, which is not the case for `pbkdf2()`.

Comment: See [here](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-pbkdf2/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.pbkdf2.pbkdf2) and notice that the callback is required when calling the function

Comment: My suggestion is to either use the synchronous function or look for another module that has what you're looking for.